# How do I change the volume control icon?

Tags: gnome, themes, volume-control, icon-themes

I recently switched to gnome 3 (love it!), but the default icon theme was a little dreary and gray, so I switched that back to ubuntu-mono-dark. But now whenever I change my volume, I get this ugly pixelated icon show up. The forum says I don't have enough reputation to post an screenshot, but it's pixelated and ugly with these fuzzy straight blue lines that turn on as the volume goes up.

I found identical images in the Humanity and Humanity-Dark icon themes (one example: /usr/share/icons/Humanity/status/24/audio-volume-high.png). I tinkered with the images by changing their names, temporarily deleting them, etc. But it had no effect on the ugly icon. What file is responsible for violating the beauty of my desktop?! Once I find it, I can replace it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to see if it helps:

Install dconf-editor:

- `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools`

Open dconf editor (from terminal `dconf-editor`). Under org > gnome > desktop > interface you will find *icon-theme* being used and you change to whatever you want/have in your system.
[image]
 If you like the *ubuntu-mono-light* icon theme you'd want to copy these icons: audio-volume-high.png, audio-volume-low.png, audio-volume-medium.png, audio-volume-muted.png into /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/your_target_folder. It could be in /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/24 or you could create one more folder for a larger set of icons, say /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/128 and place the icons in this. You could have to edit the file */usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/index.theme*. Open the file with any text editor of your choice and search for Directories=actions/16,actions/22,... ... and add your dircetory if its not there already e.g.

```
Directories=actions/16,actions/22,...,status/128,... ...
```

and further down you'd add these:

```
[places/128]
Size=128
Context=Places
Type=Scalable
```